# Appending a close "X" to a div in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, d3.js

I'm attempting to add a close-button to a div I've created in d3 that serves as a popup.

The basic div-popup, which I call with event listeners:

```
var LeafletDiv = d3.select("#content").append("div")   
                .attr("class", "county2014Tooltip")               
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .style("scrollTop", 0)
```

I want the user to be able to close the pop-up by click an X button, so I tried:

```
 var LeafletDiv = d3.select("#content").append("div")   
                .attr("class", "county2014Tooltip")               
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .style("scrollTop", 0)
        var spn = LeafletDiv.selectAll('span')
             spn.enter()
            .append("span")
                .attr("class", "spanElement") 
                .text('x')
        
                
    
       d3.selectAll("spanElement").on("mouseover", function() { 
        console.log("mouseing")
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;
       })
```

Nothing happens, and for some reason the span element w/ text is not being added to my div?

Comment: That's expected, without bound data `spn.enter()` does nothing.

Comment: What do you mean bound data?

Comment: Data bound to the selection with the `data()` method.